# Redux WP Framework. Cannot disable 'dev_mode' with if statment

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks

I have a problem.

I want to disable 'dev_mode' if 'opt_name' not redux_demo, using the if statment, but it did not work ... where does the fault ??

I found the code on [Here](https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-developer-mode-disabler/blob/master/redux-disable-devmode.php)
and I turn it into like this

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' ) ) {
    function redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin( $redux ) {
        if ( $redux->args['opt_name'] != 'redux_demo' ) {
            if ( $redux->args['dev_mode'] == true ) {
                $redux->args['dev_mode'] = false;
            }
        } else {
            if ( $redux->args['dev_mode'] == false ) {
                $redux->args['dev_mode'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'redux/construct', 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' );
}
```

the above code, I input in config.php

Thanks B4 and sorry my english is not good. :D

Comment: What is your expected result? What if $redux->args['dev_mode'] already false or not set?

Comment: @try I want the code to make the value dev_mode be false if opt_name not redux_demo, also otherwise if opt_name => redux_demo the value dev_mode be true.
dev_mode set at true. so where does the fault ??? I am New in here :)

Comment: There is no error in your code. Either the opt_name isn't 'redux_demo' or the inner if condition fails because $redux->args['dev_mode'] is everything but not true.

Comment: @try and how to get out ??? can you help me to solve this problem ??? sorry if troublesome :)

Comment: @Tyr Haha, thank you! My problem has been solved on my own. The problem is in my code placement., Should my code above, should be put in functions.php. Now the code is running well! :D . I slipshod hii :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter the args JUST for your opt_name using this:

apply_filters( "redux/args/{$this->args['opt_name']}", $this->args );

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' ) ) {
        function redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin( $redux ) {
            if ( $redux->args['opt_name'] != 'redux_demo' ) {
                $redux->args['dev_mode'] = false;
            }
        }

        add_action( 'redux/construct', 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In framework.php (for me it's from line 1281). It worked for me after making those two attr false.

```
// Force dev_mode on WP_DEBUG = true and if it's a local server
            if ( Redux_Helpers::isLocalHost() || ( Redux_Helpers::isWpDebug() ) ) {
                if ( $this->args['dev_mode'] != true ) {
                    $this->args['update_notice'] = false;
                }
                $this->dev_mode_forced  = true; // make it false
                $this->args['dev_mode'] = true; //make it false
            }
```